# How to find element value using Splinter?

Tags: python, dom, web-scraping, screen-scraping, splinter

I have following piece of html:

```
<p class="attrs"><span>foo:</span> <strong>foo</strong></p>
<p class="attrs"><span>bar:</span> <strong>bar</strong></p>
<p class="attrs"><span>foo2:</span> <strong></strong></p>
<p class="attrs"><span>description:</span> <strong>description body</strong></p>
<p class="attrs"><span>another foo:</span> <strong>foooo</strong></p>
```

I would like to get description body using splinter. I've managed to get a list of `p` using

```
browser.find_by_css("p.attrs")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
xpath = '//p[@class="attrs"]/span[text()="description:"]/following-sibling::strong'
description = browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).first.text
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you be able to get the description using find_by_tag?

**Find by Tag**

```
browser.find_by_tag('span')
```

Then go iterate through all 'span' tags and look for the value of 'description'.  I used the documentation [here](http://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/0.0.2/#all-elements-and-find-by-id)

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to acomplish using this code, if you want to try a different approach with the selenium library:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('PATH_LOCATION_TO_CHROME_DRIVER') 
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("attrs")
```

Hope this helps! replace PATH_LOCATION_TO_CHROME_DRIVER --- with the location of your chrome driver, if you google it should be first or second link to download and then place that download inside your Python's project folder.